# Can a TImage handle a 32bpp JPG Image?

Tags: delphi, jpeg, timage

For some reason, when I load a JPG image at design-time, the image shows  as a grey scale image with vertical bars reminiscent of TV scan lines. and the image is not sized properly.  The image is 500x364 32 bpp, and previews beautifully.

Is there a limitation of TImage in terms of colour depth?

Comment: Note: JPEG images are either 8bpp (grayscale) or 24bpp, there is no 32bpp JPEG format.

Comment: Can you post your JPEG?  Does it work with other full color JPEG images?  What version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The JPEG implementation in Delphi has some bugs in them.

What do you mean by 32 bit JPEG? If you mean CMYK JPEG files? If so, then you just hit a major problem area in the JPEG implementation in the JPEG unit.

Note hat there are other JPEG packages that you can download as shareware, like NativeJPG, (I don't know if there are freeware packages) that do support CMYK JPEG files correctly.

Answer (score -2):

It was a long time ago... But the answer is Yes for sure, It's just that You have to do the loading of the JPEG separately in Your code. 
I don't remember exactly how, but I remember seeing it done easily;)

Comment: -1. Too vague. Yes TImage can handle 32 bpp images, or yes there's a limitation? What does it mean to "do the loading ... separately"?